# Why do I get a compilation error of The name ... does not exist in the context in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

I keep getting the error 'The name (x) does not exist in the current context' in an asp.net application. I am aware that I must include the right `<% Page` declaration with the include directive pointing to my cs file, and the inherit must be the same class I define in there. But it seems like I'm still missing something. I've googled a while to try to find what's missing but most of the things I've seen don't seem to be related to my particular problem. Anyone care to help, please?

My code in the .aspx file (well part of it):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="App_Code/Logon.aspx.cs"   Inherits="_Logon" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="loginmat" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Label ID="matInicial" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="inptMat" Text="Ingrese  su matrícula:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="inptMat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPersist" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="sbmtMat" runat="server"
```

and in the aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Logon
/// </summary>
/// 
public class _Logon : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void LoginBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conMatriculas"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText="SELECT matricula FROM dbo.Usuarios WHERE matricula=@mat";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mat", inptMat.Text);
```

That last variable in the query is what the app doesn't reach.

Comment: Have you tried tracing to see what is stored in inptMat.Text when you get to the failure line?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Web **Application** project or an ASP.NET Web **Site** project? The code you posted is giving mixed signals: `CodeFile` implies this is a Web Site, but the lack of a `partial` keyword on the `_Logon` class implies this is a Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the namespace:

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class _Logon : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    ...........
```

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but I don't understand what a namespace would do in a case like this, where I'm just using the class to provide a Code Behind aspx page. That is, I figure out namespaces are used in larger applications where there's a need to distinguish methods in sort of nested classes, isn't it?

Comment: You have a valid point Iam trying to point out an issue with scope, You shouldn't be putting aspx pages in App_code any way as it is really for class file, they are compiled as soon as you make changes